# How to use REGEXP with escape sequences like word boundary?

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-8.0

It does not work in MySQL (8.0.5+) using ICU-REGEXP to perform a search on the word boundary.
As far as I understand it should be a-la

```
$ mysql -e 'SELECT REGEXP_LIKE("aaa abc ccc", ".*\b+abc\b+.*")'
+---------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_LIKE("aaa abc ccc", ".*\b+abc\b+.*") |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                           0 |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

but this option does not work.

Comment: What does `\b+` mean? I thought the word boundary was 0 length

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that `REGEXP_REPLACE` can match strings *partially*, and you do not need `.*` before and after a search word.

The `\` char should be escaped in order to define a literal backslash, since `\` itself allows escaping characters for the MySQL  engine. See this [MySQL 8 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html):

> **Note**
>   Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, `\n` to represent the newline character), you must double any `\` that you use in your ***expr*** and ***pat*** arguments.

Thus, you need

```
REGEXP_LIKE("aaa abc ccc", "\\babc\\b")
```

Comment: It caught me by surprise that the previous `[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]` expression is not supported any more. Now it use ICU libraries but not all new allowed expressions are documented by MySQL. To complement this answer for people who write PHP, the double backslash need to escaped also something like this: `$sql="SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('AA AAA ABAA','\\\\bAA\\\\b')";`. In fact any other language will need these double escaped backslashes.

Comment: Whether you need one, two, or four backslashes depends on the number of layers of interface you have to go through.  The final syntax is one backslash.